# Adding an answer does not update tab label

Tags: bug, android-app

After adding an answer to a question, the tab label still says "0 answers".

Comment: Caching. ITS EVERYWHERE!

Comment: I also want to be able to post more than 1 bug report every 900 seconds :-P

Comment: So many bugs, so little time.

Comment: Is this still happening, almost year later? I believe they changed lots of things since.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The tabs are gone now.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg cool, so this question should be closed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I already put my vote in

Comment: Nice, using the app (iOS) so couldn't see. :)