# Answer counter doesn't update

Tags: bug, android-app

When using Android app, if app weren't killed but was suspended on a page with answers and someone posted another answer, answer counter still shows the number of answers from before suspension.

Comment: and also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219920/refreshing-a-question-doesnt-update-the-answer-count-properly, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204425/adding-an-answer-does-not-update-tab-label